# Javascript matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, document, swap

Given a 3 x 3 randomized matrix filled with the numbers 1-9, i need to write code so that the user can click on a cell (it turns from white to orange) and then click on another cell so that the two numbers insides the cells switch and the orange cell turns back to white. this needs to continue until the user arranges the 9 numbers in order. so far this is what i have:

```
function processclick(tileId){
if(clickedcell==""){
    var  firstcell = document.getElementById(tileId);
    clickedcell = document.getElementById(tileId).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(tileId).style.backgroundColor = "#D35400";
}
else{
    firstcell.element.innerHTML = document.getElementById(tileId).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(tileId).innerHTML = clickedcell;
    firstcell.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    clickedcell = "";
}
```

For some reason, the firstcell is not changing numbers with the second cell and not changing colors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any HTML?

Comment: firstcell is local to the function, so in the else section it will not be initialized

Comment: also - `firstcell.element.innerHTML`  - should be `firstcell.innerHTML`

Comment: ok i made firstcell into a global variable and it ended up working. How would I check the arrangement of the matrix to see if its in order?

Comment: you loop through the matrix and check it - as you haven't even shown the matrix, it's hard to say

Comment: also, you're calling `document.getElementById(tileId)` three times in succession in the `if` block and twice in succession in the `else` block - not a game changer for this simple function, but you should learn how to streamline your code

Comment: *How would I check the arrangement of the matrix to see if its in order?* something like this `let testMatrix = matrix => matrix.every((line, row) => line.every((cell, col) => cell == row * 3 + col + 1));` - called with a 3x3 matrix of integers would return true if passed in `testMatrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`

Answer (score 0):

It is a but hard to answer without a HTML example, but i did you an working example on fiddle you can see here:https://jsfiddle.net/fistuks/gn8fq7fs/

I just did a table to represent your matrix:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A css rule of the background color:

```
td {
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

And this is the code:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var firstClickedTd = false;
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  var cell = cells[i];
  cell.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!firstClickedTd) {
      firstClickedTd = this;
      firstClickedTd.classList.toggle('orange');
    } else {
      var tmp = this.innerHTML;
      this.innerHTML = firstClickedTd.innerHTML;
      firstClickedTd.innerHTML = tmp;
      firstClickedTd.classList.toggle('orange');
      firstClickedTd = false;
    }
  });
}
```